# Buying a new home and had questions on electrical box

Tags: electrical-panel

[image]

Can someone take a look at this breaker box and please let me know if there is anything I should be concerned with. Its a smaller house 1300 sq 3 bed 2 bath. Ac, new electric oven, gas water heater.

Comment: Is there a label anywhere on it that says which breakers go with what circuits?

Comment: Does the kitchen have a separate cooktop and oven, or an integrated range? Also, is the dryer gas or electric?

Comment: It looks like a NEMA 3R enclosure, is this located outdoors?  Does it have a proper dead front for the breakers that you have removed to take thus picture, or is this what you’re into as soon as you swing the rain tight cover open?

Comment: I dont have the picture of the legend as im out of state and my realestate guy forgot to take one. I will work on that. The oven is all in one integrated range. Dryer is electric. Breaker box is located outdoors under a sealed cover. It does have the proper dead front.

Comment: My only question is could i run my dryer oven and ac all at the same time?

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to help me I really appreciate it.

Comment: Your main breaker is 125 A. Your 3 biggest double breakers - presumably dryer, oven and air conditioner - add up to 120 A. While in theory that would mean you only have 5 A leftover for everything else (lights, computer, other appliances, etc.) normally your large appliances don't use their full amount, and certainly not all at the same time. Should not be a problem at all.

Comment: Correction: 3 biggest = 30 + 30 + 50 = 110.

Comment: Sheesh ... whenever I think my work isn't neat enough I'm going to come back to this pic and feel better ...

Comment: No doubt im going to have someone clean it up!

Comment: Excellent picture, nice and clear.  I think the panel is OK but there may be issues with the wiring peeking out.

Comment: Don't bother, there's nothing wrong with a somewhat messy panel.   **Every conductor, including neutral, should have enough length to reach any breaker position**.  Neutral too, because GFCI.  *That excess length has to go somewhere*. Very neat panels are a nightmare because they create neatness by snipping back all "unnecessary" length. This then results in a rat's nest of wire nuts and tight wiring when inevitable reorganization is needed.  This panel is way too small and at some point you will need to rearrange for double-stuff breakers or change panel. You'll need that length then!

Comment: Agree with Harper I always add a small service loop it may not look as neat but it prevents having to pigtail inside the panel at a later date, some times just to balance loads, I would rather see a few inches of wasted wire over no slack zip tied panels any day.+

Answer (score 1):

Generally I really like how this panel is set up. Neutrals are all landed on the bus on the left. Grounds are all landed on the bus on the right.  It is a main panel, and neutral and grond buses are bonded by the wide black strap, but that's as it should be.

The red wire landed on the ground bus, I would have questions about that.

The capped wires on the left are no problem, those are simply unused circuits you might be able to put to use in the future, depending on where they go.

On the right are all 2-pole breakers, on the left 1-pole for 120V circuits.

The only thing that catches my eye is the red wires on the 120V circuits.  Follow those back to the cable they enter the box with.  They should be in a cable with a black and white wire.  Now follow the black to its breaker.  The red and black from the same cable should be on a 2-pole breaker.  These are multi-wire branch circuits, and the red and black need to switch off together.  This panel type is BR, which is a perfectly acceptable panel, and 2-pole breakers cost $9.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any red flags with the panel itself.  Neat enough for me, certainly workable, I wouldn't pay to have it messed with.

There's some black residue on the bottom of the can, hopefully that's just dirt, not scorch marks.

I see the jacket of some old cloth covered Romex coming in the KO on the lower left indicating this is a recent upgrade.  This would raise my main concern - what condition is the old wiring in?  The insulation on that wire looks OK, I don't see any cracking or brittle insulation, so it may be fine.  I'd check the first floor ceiling fixture boxes.

I can't really follow it in the photo, but it looks like that wire may go to position #11.  I also couldn't say for sure from the photo but it looks like that may be a #14 wire on a 20 amp breaker, if it is #14, it should be a 15A breaker.

*(BTW, excellent photo - well lit, clear, easy to see the details, I wonder what was used for to take it.  A lot of photos posted on diy.se are hard to see the details despite high resolution.)*